# how to setup my app engine app to send mail from my custom domain

Tags: email, google-app-engine, dns

I am porting my application on Google App Engine. As part of application I have to send email to my application users regarding their content. I am able to send mails using my google account(i.e mymailid@gmail.com) under which I have hosted my application. But that's not good. I want to send mails from support@mydomai.com/info@mydomain.com to represent my company. For that I bought a domain from godaddy.com. Now I have no clue what to do next for sending mails from that domain. Can someone help me what are all required to do that?

Note: I am new to domain registration and web-hosting technology and terminology. So, I need it in layman style

Comment: Please read the *Sending mail* section in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/

Comment: On googling I found I need a email hosting for mydomain. So, I have created one from zoho.com. Can I use the mail myname@mydomain.com, that I have created in zoho.com. Or I should have google email for business account for mail setup?

Comment: @Kekito I have signup for zoho.com mail service. Now what are the steps required to send mail from google app hosted application